# How to retrieve data in java from memo field using progress database

Tags: java, sql, openedge, progress-db

How to retrieve data in java from memo field,i am  using progress database. But it's giving error:

```
[DataDirect-Technologies][ODBC PROGRESS driver][PROGRESS]Column Doc_Desc in table PUB.GLDOCHDR has value exceeding its max length or precision.
```

Wrote code like this sql:

```
selectSQL="select Doc_Desc from PUB.GLDOCHDR where Doc_Desc like '%:%' and Doc_Desc like '%@%'";
```

Retrieving data like this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
while( rs.next())
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rs.getAsciiStream("Doc_Desc")));                   
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress (OpenEdge) has two "personalities" -- SQL and 4GL.

The 4GL (or "ABL") engine is most commonly used and it does not care how wide a field is.  All data is variable width.  The width is just a suggestion for display formatting purposes and is routinely ignored by programmers.

Naturally this gives SQL tools fits.

There is a tool provided to ease your pain -- "dbtool" will scan the database and adjust the "sql-width" to reflect the actual maximum width that it finds in the data.  This is commonly run on a regular basis (usually weekly or monthly) in most Progress shops that use SQL.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P159769